# Emoji replaced with random string ressource

Tags: android, android-resources

When i display an Emoji in my app (with `EmojiCompat` or any other library, doesn't matter) in API `>21` i get this nice result:

> FooBar

However, if I display this text on a device `<=21`, the device decides to throw a random string resource in. (Not really random, the same thrown in resource is displayed every time). e.g.:

> FooBar! Hello World!

The `Hello World!` ressource is a whole different resource, not even near the one in strings.xml.
This happens on every device..

ProGuard is activated, shrinkresources too.

What can i do to fix this issue?

Comment: @Tigger `blabla` is an actual string located in my `strings.xml`. for other occurences there could be another emoji with another randomly attached string resource e.g. `Whats up Settings` (where 'Settings' is another string resource)  (Edited for better understanding)